# Block Platform parameter is not instantiated in Simulink

Tags: nxt

I used Simulink to write a program for LEGO Midstorms NXT. I can post the design if needed. The problem is that when I want to run it on hardware, it gives the following error:

**Lego mindstorms NXT motor block (mask) doesn't have a parameter named blockPlatform**

When I dig into the motor mask, there are 3 parameters, but the 3rd, which is blockParameter is not visible.

What should I do to overcome this? 
I looks like a bug.

[image]

And this is the details of the mask:

[image]